# How to know where an object was instantiated in Python?

Tags: python

I define a class in a given python module. From a few other python files I will create instances of said class. The instances register themselves at object creation, ie during `__init__()`, in a singleton registry object. From a third type of python file I would like to access the registry, look at the objects therein and be able to figure out in which files these objects were created beforehand.

A code sample might look as follows:

Python module file : '/Users/myself/code/myobjectmodule.py':

```
@singleton
class Registry(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.objects = {}

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, object_name):
        self.object_name = object_name
        Registry().objects[self.object_name] = self
```

`singleton` decorator according to http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#examples

Instance creation python files : '/Users/myself/code/instance_creation_python_file.py':

```
from myobjectmodule import MyObject

A = MyObject('Foo')
```

Third python file : '/Users/myself/code/registry_access.py':

```
from myobjectmodule import Registry

registry = Registry()
foo = registry.objects['Foo']
```

Now, I would like to have a method `foo.get_file_of_object_creation()`.

How can I implement this method?

#### Edit:

The reason for this approach is the following scenario:
1. A framework defines a set of objects that shall specify data sources and contain the data after loading (MyObject).
2. Apps making use of this framework shall specify these objects and make use of them. Each app is saved in a .py file or a folder that also specifies the name of the app via its name.
3. An engine provides functionality for all apps, but needs to know, for some features, which of the objects originate from which app / file.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Perhaps we can come up with some alternative solution, because this whole thing seems a little odd.  That said, if you're really convinced you need this, take a look at the `inspect` module for what you need to figure out who is calling your __init__ method.

Comment: Are you sure the file in which the object was created is really what you want? What if a program delegates all its `MyObject` creation to a `utils.MyObjectMaker` helper, and your registry sees all the objects as being created from `/path/to/utils.pyc`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without getting into the merits of why would you want to do this, here is a way to do it:

```
# assume the file is saved as "temp.py"

import inspect

class RegisteredObject(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_instance = super(RegisteredObject, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        stack_trace = inspect.stack()
        created_at = '%s:%d' % (
            stack_trace[1][1], stack_trace[1][2])
        new_instance.created_at = created_at 
        return new_instance

    def get_file_of_object_creation(self):
        return self.created_at

class MyObject(RegisteredObject):
    pass

def create_A():
    return MyObject()

def create_B():
    return MyObject()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = create_A()
    t2 = create_B()
    t3 = create_A()
    t4 = create_B()
    t5 = MyObject()
    print '"t1" was created at "%s"' % t1.get_file_of_object_creation()
    print '"t2" was created at "%s"' % t2.get_file_of_object_creation()
    print '"t3" was created at "%s"' % t3.get_file_of_object_creation()
    print '"t4" was created at "%s"' % t4.get_file_of_object_creation()
    print '"t5" was created at "%s"' % t5.get_file_of_object_creation()
```

Output:

```
$ python temp.py
"t1" was created at "temp.py:19"
"t2" was created at "temp.py:22"
"t3" was created at "temp.py:19"
"t4" was created at "temp.py:22"
"t5" was created at "temp.py:29"
```

Answer (score 8):

All the caveats about this only being a good idea for debugging aside, you can use the `inspect` module.

```
import inspect

def get_caller():
    return inspect.stack()[2]   # 1 is get_caller's caller

def trace_call():
    _, filename, line, function, _, _ = get_caller()
    print("Called by %r at %r:%d" % (function, filename, line))

def main():
    trace_call()

main()
```

produces

```
Called by 'main' at 'trace.py':11
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is slightly different in that it does not use `inspect.stack`, considering I observed it to be particularly slow in Python 3.

```
import inspect


class Locatable:

    def __new__(cls, *_args, **_kwargs):
        # Background: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/04/16/python-object-creation-sequence
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        obj.location = obj._initialization_location()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
        return obj

    @staticmethod
    def _initialization_location():
        # Background: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42653524/
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        while frame:
            if frame.f_code.co_name == '<module>':
                return {'module': frame.f_globals['__name__'], 'line': frame.f_lineno}
            frame = frame.f_back

    @property
    def name(self):
        module_name = self.__module__
        class_name = self.__class__.__qualname__  # pylint: disable=no-member
        return module_name + '.' + class_name
```

The above is a base class that can be inherited from.

The `location` attribute should contain the name of the module where the class is instantiated, e.g. `mypackage.mymodule`.

Comment: This is the only answer to get the module name, rather than the file path.