# Python find the file where a typing alias (e.g. Union,...) is declared

Tags: python, python-typing

How can I find the file in which the typing alias annotation has been declared/created ?

For example:

```py
# In a.py
Number = Union[int, float]
```

I would like a function which extract where the file in which the typing alias was originally created:

```py
get_file(Number) == 'path/to/a.py'
```

I cannot call `inspect.getfile(Number)` as `Number` is a `_GenericAlias` instance, and not a new class.

A use case is to generate HTML documentation. The `Number` doc page should point out to the original file alias declaration.

A really simplified example:

```py
from my_types import Number

def f(x: Number):
  pass
```

In `document.py`

```py
def document_fn(f):
  for name, annotation in f.__annotations__.items():
    print(f'Annotation declared in {get_file(annotation)}')
```

The current solutions  I found to find where object are created would require calling `inspect.stack()` in the `_GenericAlias` constructor: [How to know where an object was instantiated in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147050/how-to-know-where-an-object-was-instantiated-in-python)

I guess I could try to patch the `typing._GenericAlias` to inject the tracking code but I would strongly prefer to avoid this as it rely on implementation details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you want is not tracked anywhere. Your best option is probably to statically inspect the source code, without importing it or actually generating a `_GenericAlias` at all. (Static inspection is the primary and best-supported use case of type annotations.)